# Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-transform

I am a computer scientist and not a mathematician.  I do not know how to edit questions on this site, so I am rephrasing a problem I came across while reading on the explicit construction of expander graphs by Margulis using discrete Fourier transform:

Let $H$ be a finite Abelian group. It has $\vert H \vert$ distinct characters, where character of $ H $ is a homomorphism $\chi : H \to \mathbb C$, that is $\chi (g+h) = \chi (g) \chi (h)$ for all $g, h \in H$.  The characters of $H= {\mathbb Z_n \times \mathbb Z_n} $  are exactly  $ \chi_a (x) = \omega ^ {\langle a, x \rangle} $ for $a, x \in \mathbb Z_n ^2 $, where $\omega = e^\frac {2 \pi i}{n}$. These characters form an orthonormal basis for the space of functions $f: H \to \mathbb C$.
Given $f :  \mathbb Z_n ^2 \to  \mathbb C $   we can write the Fourier coefficients of $f$ as
$$\hat{f} (x) = \langle f, \chi _ x \rangle = \frac {1}{\vert H \vert } \sum_ {y \in H} \overline {f(y)} \chi _ x {(y)}$$

Furthermore:
Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ non-singular matrix over  $\mathbb Z_n$  and $b\in  \mathbb Z_n ^2$.
Define $g(x) = f(Ax+b)$.
Then the Fourier coefficients of $g$ are given by
$$\hat{g} (y) = \omega ^ {- \langle A^{-1} b, y \rangle}  \hat{f} ({(A ^ {-1})^ T } y) $$

Can anyone kindly show me how the last equation was obtained but in simple steps?

Comment: you might want to disclose your source?

Comment: Probably you should ask in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/  When you ask there, include some relevant definitions (or links to them, or ask their meaning): Fourier transform for function on a group (like $\mathbb Z_n^2$).  $\omega$.  "Non-singluar" for a matrix over a non-field.

Comment: @JulesLamers ... of course.  I refer to .meta too often, it seems.

Comment: you have a dangling parantheses at the right hand side of the last equation--please fix. yes this should be in math.stackexchange

Comment: I Made some changes as suggested and the new text is: